# Melting and freezing ice

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, condensed-matter

Suppose I have two ice cubes and I want to stick them without any external material. Can I achieve this by keeping both on one another and extract some more energy from them ( by placing them in freezer) ??

I just want to know the answer ( in yes or no ) ??

Answer (score 0):

No if they are dry before you put them in the freezer. Yes if the surfaces in contact are wet (e.g. because of surface melting). That's what common sense suggests. Why not try it?

Comment: I had the same intuition.